# How can I limit the number of maximum selections for 1 selecting option of 20 JCombobox? javafor ex

Tags: java, arrays, jcombobox, limiting

I have 9 (+ default) selectable options (all the same for the 20) for my JComboBoxes. 
The 20 are part of 2 JComboBox array. (10-10 for each). 
I want to limit them like this:
If there is 4 selected from  (for example) option 4 and the user selects a 5th 
one of it, one of them jumps back to default to keep the limit of 4.

How Can I do it ? 
for ex:

```
for (int i = 0; i < roles1.length; i++) {
            roles1[i] = new JComboBox();
            roles1[i].setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Not Selected", "PartnerInCrime", "Driver",
                    "Gunman", "Coordinator", "Hacker", "Distraction", "GadgetGuy", "Bruglar", "ConMan" }));
            roles1[i].setBounds(boxPlace, 200, 100, 20);
            boxPlace += 105;
            getFrame().getContentPane().add(roles1[i]);

        }
```

Comment: would you please add some codes?

Comment: Done, as you wished :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion which is supposed to lead you in the right direction.

First of all, you have to add an ActionListener to each ComboBox, that calls a method which compares all selections with your current one.

```
roles1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       // get the current selection
       JComboBox currentBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
       String currentSelection = (String)currentBox.getSelectedItem();

       // call the method and hand in your current selection
       checkForSelectionExceeding(currentSelection);            

    }
});
```

In your scanning method you should memorize the amount of matches while scanning. If your limit is exceeded, reset the current box to default and stop scanning. Something like this:

```
private void checkForSelectionExceeding(String currentSelection){
   int matches = 0;

   for(int i=0; i<roles1.length; i++) {
      if(roles1[i].getSelectedItem().equals(currentSelection)) {
         matches++;
      }

      if(matches > 4) {
         roles1[i].setSelectedItem("Not Selected");
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

You only have to refactor this solution a little in order to scan both arrays sequentially.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot!

Comment: In this case, every time the user select from any combo box, it has to loop through the entire array and look for every selected value.

Comment: At John: I'd say that both approaches have their pro's and con's. My solution maybe needs a few milliseconds longer due to the needed loop. Your suggestion needs an extra map to hold the referenced information. But in case of just 20 ComboBoxes neither of these con's is really a matter. -- @Victor: I'd really appreciate if you could mark or upvote the solution that helped you. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Just done! Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, I have an idea that you may start from:

```
// create global HashMap that can records the occurrence of the selection of each item
Map<String, Integer> reference = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
// populate it
reference.put("PartnerInCrime", 0);
reference.put("Driver", 0);
reference.put("Gunman", 0);
reference.put("Coordinator", 0);
reference.put("Hacker", 0);
reference.put("Distraction", 0);
reference.put("GadgetGuy", 0);
reference.put("Bruglar", 0);
reference.put("ConMan", 0);

// then for every JComboBox in your array -> add action item listener to observe and control the selection like this


for(JComboBox<String> jcb : roles1){
    jcb.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){ // decrement record
           if(!ie.getItem().toString().equals("Not Selected")){
             reference.put(ie.getItem().toString(), reference.get(ie.getItem().toString()) -1);
           }
        }
         else if(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
           if(!ie.getItem().toString().equals("Not Selected")){
             if(reference.get(ie.getItem().toString())>=4){ // if already selected 4 of them
                jcb.setSelectedIndex(0); // return to the default
              } 
              else{ // else record the selection 
                   reference.put(ie.getItem().toString(), reference.get(ie.getItem().toString()) +1);
              }    
          } 
        }
      }
   });
}
```